# Combobox SelectedValue.ToString is always null WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, combobox

I have a `DateTime` property where I want to save the Date and the Time of something. Therefore I made a `DatePicker` in `WPF` where I can choose the Date. Next to it I put a `Combobox` with some time entries.

[image: 1]

Now I want to join the time which I selected in the `combobox` with the `DateTime` of the `DatePicker` so that the Default value of `00:00:00` gets replaced by my value I selected in the `comboBox`. How do I do that?

Here some code snippets. I fill my combo boxes like that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                string minute;

                if (j == 0)
                {
                    minute = "00";
                }
                else
                {
                    minute = "30";
                }


                //view.cmbStartZeit.Items.Add(i.ToString() + ":" + j.ToString());
                //startZeit.Content = i.ToString() + ":" + minute;
                //endZeit.Content = i.ToString() + ":" + minute;

                StartTime.Items.Add(i.ToString("00") + ":" + minute);
                EndTime.Items.Add(i.ToString("00") + ":" + minute);
            }
```

StartTime and EndTime are my ComboBoxes

I want to Join my `DatePicker` and the time in the combo boxes. I found a Code Sample but It does not work.

```
((DateTime)view.StartDate.SelectedDate).Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Convert.ToDouble((view.StartTime.SelectedValue.ToString()).Split(':')[0]))).Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(Convert.ToDouble((view.StartTime.SelectedValue.ToString()).Split(':')[1])));
```

`StartDate` is my `DatePicker`. It always gives me null at `StartTime.SelectedValue.ToString()`

If somebody knows another way to do that, without using third party kits or stuff like that please tell me. I have to use the native `WPF` stuff (it's for school)

Many thanks in advance

B.Pumpkin

Comment: Can you share some code snippets that you are using and the error you faced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a similar example works fine for getting `StartTime.SelectedValue.ToString()`.

There are other problems though:

DateTime.Add is a non mutating method, and just returns a new DateTime object. 
So first thing you need to do is set the new DateTime to your StartDate object. Also you are parsing minutes, and hours in opposite order (but there is a better way to parse it, see below).

Here is what I did to make it work:

```
var time = TimeSpan.Parse(startTime.SelectedValue.ToString());

startDate.SelectedDate = ((DateTime)startDate.SelectedDate).Add(time);
```

Full (simple), working example:

```
<StackPanel>
            <DatePicker Name="startDate" />
            <ComboBox Name="startTime" SelectionChanged="StartTime_OnSelected" />
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                string minute;

                if (j == 0)
                {
                    minute = "00";
                }
                else
                {
                    minute = "30";
                }


                //view.cmbStartZeit.Items.Add(i.ToString() + ":" + j.ToString());
                //startZeit.Content = i.ToString() + ":" + minute;
                //endZeit.Content = i.ToString() + ":" + minute;

                startTime.Items.Add(i.ToString("00") + ":" + minute);
            }
        }
    }

    private void StartTime_OnSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var time = TimeSpan.Parse(startTime.SelectedValue.ToString());

        // startDate.SelectedDate could be null, so do some checking before
        startDate.SelectedDate = ((DateTime)startDate.SelectedDate).Add(time);
    }
}
```